# How do I create clickable text in cmd console for python?

Tags: python, windows

I'm trying to create a text rpg and I'd like to include clickable text inside the console. Like for example the menu would be like:

Continue
New Game
Quit

Usually, I would associate numbers with each command and have the user input that, but it would be a lot better if the user could just click on the text, and it would run a function or a code snippet that would carry out whatever I wanted. Is there a way to do this in Python 3?

Comment: Pleas read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Well, if you're looking for a graphical interface you can try tkinter

Comment: VoidTwo, I don’t think Shubham wants a graphical interface.

Comment: I have found a solution, but it will be immensely difficult to implement, it will vary from os to os, it may vary from computer to computer or run to run, and it is not guaranteed to work.